# Adding new Dialog to legacy C++ app (VS2017) results in many errors. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, atl

This is a legacy C++ app. It's been ported from VS 6.0, to VS2015, and now to VS2017. In 2017, I add a dialog via the menus/resource wizards. The act of this dialog causes all kinds of issues with ATL. (Error examples below...)

```
   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include\afxbutton.h(184): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'SelectFont'
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'SelectObject'
\afxbutton.h(184): error C3646: 'SelectObject': unknown override specifier
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'pDC'
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2065: 'pDC': undeclared identifier
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2096: 'HFONT': A data member cannot be initialized with a parenthesized initializer
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2433: 'CMFCButton::HFONT': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
\afxbutton.h(184): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
\afxbutton.h(184): note: see usage of 'pDC'
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2327: 'CMFCButton::HFONT': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
\afxbutton.h(184): error C2091: function returns function
\afxbutton.h(203): error C2327: 'CMFCButton::HFONT': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'SelectFont'
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'SelectObject'
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C3646: 'SelectObject': unknown override specifier
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'pDesc'
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2065: 'pDesc': undeclared identifier
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2096: 'HFONT': A data member cannot be initialized with a parenthesized initializer
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): note: see usage of 'pDesc'
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2327: 'CMFCFontComboBox::HFONT': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): error C2091: function returns function
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'SelectObject'
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C3646: 'SelectObject': unknown override specifier
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'lpszName'
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2065: 'lpszName': undeclared identifier
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2096: 'HFONT': A data member cannot be initialized with a parenthesized initializer
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2086: 'BOOL CMFCFontComboBox::HFONT': redefinition
\afxfontcombobox.h(45): note: see declaration of 'CMFCFontComboBox::HFONT'
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): note: see usage of 'lpszName'
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2327: 'CMFCFontComboBox::HFONT': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
\afxfontcombobox.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

The culprit is #include "afxcontrolbars.h" which is auto added by the IDE. Not sure if I have to link to another version of ATL, change the include order, or what. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: SelectFont() is not a macro.  Unless you got the #include order wrong and got windowsx.h included first.  We can't see it.

Comment: Show us what you included to the file... for me it looks like a simple syntax error at the top of you cpp file or any of the first headers

Answer (score 0):

I moved the #include "afxcontrolbars.h" before any other afx includes and this resolved this issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had the same problem and this fixed it in MFC.